mechanical vs electronic shutter
could someone explain me why there is a mechanical shutter in digaital cameras (well, no tall but most of them)?
If I understand correctly, electronic shutter (ES) reads the data line by line (or few lines at once, doesn't really matter). This can, for example, introduce rolling shutter, since reading the whole sensor take some time.
But how can mechanical shutter (MS) prevents this? It doesn't make the sensor readout time any faster. Is it that if the MS is closed, the sensor is kept in the dark and so it has all the photons from the scene just sitting there waiting until they are read, while without MS the sensor is still exposed to the light and therefore still 'exposing'?
Also I'm not clear why many cameras has better dynamic range and signal to noise ratio if using MS instead of ES. Here is an example for R6 Mk II:


With electronic shutter each row (or group of rows) cannot be activated until the previous row(s) have been read out; regardless of the shutter speed. Higher SS's are accomplished by energizing the row(s) for ever shorter durations, but the readout speed remains the same. This results in time gaps between adjoining rows (which exaggerates the rolling shutter effect), and a total time gap between first/last rows.
E.g. for a typical camera the readout for the whole sensor may be 1/100s; so the entire sensor exposure requires no less than 1/100s, even if the exposure is only 1/1000s (total time rows are energized/recording). Changing the shutter speed doesn't change the time gap between adjoining rows, or the first/last rows (unless longer than readout).
With the mechanical shutter the entire sensor is energized simultaneously and there is no time gap between the exposure of adjoining rows. However, there is still a time gap between the first and last row; and mechanical shutter is still prone to some rolling shutter effect because of that. With mechanical shutter changing the SS does change the time gap between the first and last rows, so higher SS's reduce the likelihood of the rolling shutter effect being apparent.
Some cameras increase the readout speed for electronic shutter in an attempt to compensate somewhat, which makes it more prone to packet errors (noise). And sometimes the increase is accomplished in conjunction with a reduction in the bit depth (processing accuracy), which further increases the potential for errors (noise). Both potentially result in less dynamic range (signal above noise).

Going by https://docs.baslerweb.com/electronic-shutter-types cameras without a global shutter can only reset, expose, and read out.  There's no way to not take in more light while waiting to read out. As a result the readout of each line has to happen immediately after exposure is done, and the start of exposure has to be shifted one read time after the line before to keep exposure consistent. With a mechanical shutter the readout can happen in the dark and after the exposure ends without problems.


Could someone explain me why there is a mechanical shutter in digital cameras (well, not all but most of them)?

Because the fastest mechanical shutters can transit the sensor faster than the sensor can be read out line by line.
With a mechanical shutter the curtains always transit the sensor at the same speed. What changes the exposure time is how long after the first curtain begins to open does the second curtain begin to close. With very short exposure times the second curtain is following the first curtain very closely, so that there is only a narrow slit allowing a very narrow portion of the sensor to be exposed at any given time.

The entire sensor is energized just before the first curtain opens and remains energized until the second curtain has closed. Then it is read out and cleared with the 2nd curtain still closed.
Top tier cameras have mechanical curtain transit times in the range of 2.5-4 milliseconds (1/400 - 1/250 seconds). Most sensors up until very recently took at least twice that, and many still take much more than twice that to read the sensor electronically.
The faster transit times mean the time difference between one edge of the frame and the other is less than when electronic shutter is used which takes longer to sequentially expose and read out each line of the sensor from one edge to the other.
